# Apple business Manger account shows domain verification failed

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-developer-account, apple-developer-enterprise

How can we revive domain in Apple business manager account once domain verification is failed? In business account there is no option to revive again once failed.

domain is hosted on GoDaddy and i have uploaded TXT Record over there as mentioned in Apple business manager account link. how can we revive failed domain again?